# Magento 2 - display none for emails less styles

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can I use

```
display: none
```

for inline class in _email-extend.less or email.less

without removing element from html structure in Magento Sales email that is send to customer?

When I use it the html element with class that have display: none is removed from html output that is send to a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [printscreen](https://goo.gl/qOKJV9) and modify email template, you can remove element or use css style.

Comment: But what I meant is that Magento remove element from my custom email template if I add class with `display: none` for that element. The div will be in template but when M2 will send it you won't see it in the output. You can test it in the preview also.

Comment: just delete the items that are visible in the template, else use `dispaly: none`

Comment: But I want this elements to be there! I want use media queries to show some in mobile... and for desktop I want hide it using display: none.. but it removes it

Comment: see print screen of the answer, the bottom is "Template Styles" where you can use media query